# Use GoogleFinance Currency Conversion on Sum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, currency, google-finance, currency-exchange-rates

I'm trying to use GoogleFinance currency conversion on a sum but can't get the correct format. My cell is as follows:

```
 =SUM(((IMPORTRANGE("sheet-key","H2:H300"))/100*40)+(IMPORTRANGE("sheet-key","H2:H300")))
```

I want the results of the sum to be then converted from GBP into USD. I tried adding `&GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")` to the end but that's obviously wrong. I can get it to work if I put the conversion in an adjacent cell but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with, just making sure that you understand the `IMPORTRANGE` function. Usually this function yields an array of data (in your case 299 values). But in your case this formula fails to yield the array. If the given formula...

```
=SUM(((IMPORTRANGE("sheet-key","H2:H300"))/100*40)+(IMPORTRANGE("sheet-key","H2:H300")))
```

...works, then you get **only** the result of the first cell (`H2`), i.e. just this: `H2/100*40+H2`. All the remaining cells (`H3:H300`) are not processed. Do you really want that? If so, then OK, just proceed to the solution.

If you actually want the whole range (`H2:H300`) to get processed you should use this formula:

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(((IMPORTRANGE("sheet-key","H2:H300"))/100*40)),ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("sheet-key","H2:H300")))
```

**The solution.**

To do a conversion you should multiply your result by the currency conversion rate using `*` symbol:

```
*GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")
```

as opposed to

```
&GoogleFinance("CURRENCY:GBPUSD")
```

**Note:** `GoogleFinance()` is ever updating.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in marking this. You've really helped thank you !